# Array Object sorting is not working for large length data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Today I came across with one issue, I don't it this issue is coming because of code or bugs in Javascript. I tried to sort object array, which is like this

```
const array = [{
text:'one'
count:5
},
{
text:'two'
count:5
},
{
text:'three'
count:5
},
{
text:'four'
count:5
}]
```

Now I need to sort the object array based on the count index. I tried with these piece of code

```
Array.prototype.sortBy = function (p) {
          return this.slice(0).sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a[p] > b[p]) ? 1 : (a[p] < b[p]) ? -1 : 0;
          });
  }
   console.log(array.sortBy('count'))
```

Here sorting is working fine when I have object array length as less than 100, but won't work when I have more than that length. I tried with some Npm packages also. But it doesn't work. Help me

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "won't work"? Are you getting errors? Is it not sorted at all? Or badly? Please be specific and ideally create a [mre]. It works for me with a length of 200: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/bdfgs624/

Comment: [I can't reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/doxomuletu/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

You're making it too complicated for no gain, you can just rely on the `.sort` method

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/_Light/pen/GRRzGmq) to show it working with 500 elements, just to be sure

```js
const array = [{
    text: 'one',
    count: 3
  }, {
    text: 'two',
    count: 1
  }, {
    text: 'three',
    count: 2
  }, {
    text: 'four',
    count: 4
}];

let sorted = array.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count);

console.log(sorted);
```